# Errata in the Manuals

Tags: errors, documentation

After discovering quite a few errata in a to-be-anonymous manual, I really want to be helpful and point them out...

> Is it appropriate to email the maintainer with a list of errata and inherently assume there isn't a running list you could contribute to?

I would think such a list be misplaced, considering how relatively trivial it is to incorporate changes, but I'd *really* hate to be the odd one out.  Saying it's a popular package is an understatement, but it's not part of the core LaTeX distribution (`article`, `letter`, etc).

Comment: As a package author, I'm always happiest if I get bug reports, _etc._ 'directly'. Since my stuff is nowadays all on GitHub, the issue tracker is the ideal place, but the e-mail address I give in my docs is the other 'preferred' contact method. I suspect other authors are the same: it's hard to keep on top of ever potential bug report on lists, _etc._

Comment: So, if the code is hosted on GitHub / Bitbucket / *etc*, an issue tracker (if integrated) would probably be the best place?

Comment: I'd say so: a tracker is handy as you can't loose the issue in a mass of e-mails, other people can see it and of course it's possible to provide an easy-to-apply fix as well as the report itself :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a package author, I second @JosephWright: I would also prefer to get bug reports directly (preferrably per mail, but the laggy sourceforge bug trackers would also do the job).

Generally, I think that people would be happy to accept any kind of constructive approaches to improve quality - even if it is posted at the wrong place (they can still redirect them). Even if someone has paused his maintenance efforts and cannot answer directly, you would not loose anything. In such a case, you could post such requests as tickets in bug trackers, hoping that these have a higher visibility than email for such people. But again: I believe that email would be better.

If you plan to actively correct stuff, you may want to optimize your own time by asking the package author for the most recent (unstable?) manual version. At least that appears to be appropriate for stuff which is under development.